# Go basics: What is the diference between calling a method on struct and calling it on a pointer to that struct?

Tags: go

Supoose that I have a `Vertex` type

```
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}
```

and I've defined a method

```
func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

What's the difference between those two calls ? (both of them return the same result)

```
v1 := Vertex{3, 4}
fmt.Println(v1.Abs())

v2 := &Vertex{3, 4}
fmt.Println(v2.Abs())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version is the equivalent of

```
var v1 Vertex
v1.X = 3
v1.y = 4
fmt.Println((&v1).Abs)
```

The second version is the equivalent of

```
var v2 *Vertex
v2 = new(Vertex)
v2.X = 3
v2.y = 4
fmt.Println(v2.Abs)
```

So the only substantial difference is that `v1` is a value and `v2` is a pointer to a value of type `Vertex`.

Comment: if so, there is no difference between using a value and a pointer to that value ?

Comment: @tarrsalah: Of course that's not true in the general case. For example, one can only dereference a pointer value, not a plain value. The automatic address taking is discussed [here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values): _"As with selectors, a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer: pt.Mv is equivalent to (*pt).Mv._", _"As with method calls, a reference to a non-interface method with a pointer receiver using an addressable value will automatically take the address of that value: t.Mv is equivalent to (&t).Mv."_

Comment: Thanks for the concise explication.